convert left shifted LSB bits to 1
I need to convert LSB 0 to 1 in left shift:
x=5;
int num = 0x02;//0b00000010
shiftVal = num << x;// 0b01000000

shiftVal should convert to 0b01011111

Remember to be careful left shifting signed integer values. Left shifting set bits into or past the MSB or left shifting negative values is UB.Where practical, it's better to use unsigned integers for bit shifting.

Simply set them to 1 using the or operator. To get all one bits just do (1 << x) - 1
hiftVal = (num << x) | ((1 << x) - 1);

See also

Understanding the arithmetic in `(1 << j) - 1`
Creating a mask with N least significant bits set
Why does (x-1) toggle all the bits from the rightmost set bit of x?


This can be done with three operations:
shiftVal = ~(~ (unsigned) num << x);

First, we convert to unsigned. The reason for this is discussed below, but, in ordinary modern C implementations that use two’s complement, this is merely a semantic type change. It does not generate an actual machine operation.
Then we complement the value, shift, and complement the result. Since all the original bits are complemented twice, they have their original values in the result. But any new zero bits brought in by the shift are changed to ones in the result.
Due to the complement, we could have a negative value when the original value was not negative, and the behavior of shifting that is not defined by the C standard. Hence we convert to unsigned, then do the complements and shifting, and let the assignment convert back to the type of shiftVal (presumably int). As long as the original code had defined behavior (its shift was defined, producing a result representable in int), this new code will also have defined behavior. (However, it may be preferable to change the types of num and shiftVal to unsigned, depending on the situation.)
